# problems with conditional statement based off sizeof c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and and am working on a program that has is a simple dvd rental program. I am having issues with case 3 & 4 specifically. Maybe I am misunderstanding the purpose behind sizeof. What I am trying to have it do is tell if the char array is empty and if it is allow the user to check it out by putting their name in and if it is not available give them a response saying that it is not available. case 4 should do the opposite and allow them to check it in. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>


using namespace std;


const int arrSize = 5;
struct dvdStruct //distance struct
{
int id;
char title[51] = { 0 };
char rating[5] = { 0 };
double price;
char borrower[51] = { 0 };

} dvd;

dvdStruct dvds[arrSize] = {};
int userSelection; //intput variable for main menu selection
int borrowId (0);
int borrowIdReturn(0);
//void initalize();


int main() {
int size(0);
dvds[0].id = 1;
dvds[1].id = 2;
dvds[2].id = 3;
dvds[3].id = 4;
dvds[4].id = 5;

strcpy(dvds[0].title, "Fast 1");
strcpy(dvds[1].title, "Fast 2");
strcpy(dvds[2].title, "Fast 3");
strcpy(dvds[3].title, "Fast 4");
strcpy(dvds[4].title, "Fast 5");

strcpy(dvds[0].rating, "PG - 13");
strcpy(dvds[1].rating, "PG - 13");
strcpy(dvds[2].rating, "PG - 13");
strcpy(dvds[3].rating, "PG - 13");
strcpy(dvds[4].rating, "PG - 13");

dvds[0].price = '19.1';
dvds[1].price = '19.2';
dvds[2].price = '19.3';
dvds[3].price = '19.4';
dvds[4].price = '19.5';

strcpy(dvds[0].borrower, "");
cout << strlen(dvds[0].borrower) << endl;
strcpy(dvds[1].borrower, "\0");
strcpy(dvds[2].borrower, "\0");
strcpy(dvds[3].borrower, "\0");
strcpy(dvds[4].borrower, "\0");

do {
    cout << "1.Display All DVD’s" << endl << "2.Display DVD Detail" << endl << "3.Check Out a DVD" << endl << "4.Check In a DVD" << endl << "5.Exit" << endl;
    cin >> userSelection; //Input from the user.

    switch (userSelection)
    {
    case 1:

        for (int i = 0; i < arrSize; i++)
        {
            std::cout << dvds[i].title << "' " << dvds[i].rating << " " << dvds[i].borrower << endl;
        }
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
        break;
    case 2:
        int dvdNum;
        cout << "Enter a DVD number:";
        cin >> dvdNum;
        std::cout << dvds[dvdNum - 1].title << "' " << dvds[dvdNum - 1].rating << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("CLS");
        break;
    case 3:
        cout << "Enter and id:";
        cin >> borrowId;


            if (strlen(dvds[borrowId-1].borrower) == 0)
            {
                cout << "Enter your name: ";
                cin >> dvds[borrowId-1].borrower;
            }

            else
            {
                cout << "This dvd is not available" << endl;
            }
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
            break;

    case 4:
        cout << "Enter and id:";
        cin >> borrowIdReturn;


            if (strlen(dvds[borrowIdReturn - 1].borrower) == 0)
            {
                cout << "This dvd is available" << endl;

            }

            else
            {
                cout << "Your DVD has been returned " << endl;
                strcpy(dvds[borrowIdReturn - 1].borrower, "\0");
            }
            system("pause");
            system("CLS");
        break;
    case 5:
        return 0;
        break;


    }
} while (userSelection == 1 || userSelection == 2 || userSelection == 3 || userSelection == 4);


}
```

Comment: You probably want to use `strlen()`, not `sizeof()`.

Comment: stdlen? something in the new c++17 standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof()` gives you the size of an object. The size of the object is always the same, no matter what's in the object. In fact, `sizeof()` is calculated at compile time, and its value could not be affected, in any way, by whatever happens at runtime.

C++ code should use `std::string`, instead of `char` arrays, in most cases. `std::string`'s `empty()` method indicates whether the string is empty.

If you still insist on working with C-style `char` arrays, and C-style `'\0'` terminated strings, use the C `strlen()` function to check if the character array contains nothing but a leading `'\0'`, indicating an empty string.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. For this I am trying to get it to work using char array's I am still running into an issue with the input if I put  firstname it works but if I put firstname_lastname it doesn't. is that a problem with using cin? What could I use in place of that? I have updated the code above.

Comment: operator>> extract whitespace delimited words. Many beginners in C++ are led astray by the >> operator. They're taught needlessly to use it, when they should be using std::getline(). If you want to read a line of input, do not use >>. Always use std::getline(), that's what it's there for. The >> is not, I repeat, NOT, for reading a line of text.

Comment: That make sense however when I change to getline I receive and error in visual studio that says "no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list"

Comment: I am confident that std::getline() works just fine. You must not be using it with a std::string, correctly. Since I have no idea what you did this time, I'm not sure how you can expect me to tell you what you did wrong.